# Unit testing Asynchronous code in the callback function of InteractionRequest in PRISM

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, callback, async-await, prism

I have the following reoccurring pattern in my code which I would like to unit test.

```
public class MyViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    public readonly IService DoSomethingService;

    private bool _IsBusy;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return _IsBusy; }
        set
        {
             if (_IsBusy != value)
             {
                 _IsBusy = value;
                 RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsBusy);
             }
    }
}

public ICommand DisplayInputDialogCommand { get; private set; }
public InteractionRequest<Confirmation> Input_InteractionRequest{ get; private set; }

 // ctor
 public MyViewModel(IService service)
 {
    DoSomethingService = service;

    DisplayInputDialogCommand  = new AsyncRelayCommand(DisplayInputDialog);
    Input_InteractionRequest = new InteractionRequest<Confirmation>();
 }

  private async Task DisplayInputDialog()
  {
            Input_InteractionRequest.Raise(
                new Confirmation() {
                    Title = "Please provide input...",
                    Content = "test"
                },
                await ProcessInput
            );
          // At this point I want the return the task from the call back method so the unit test can wait on it. So the question is ,how to refactor the code to make this possible
   }

   private async void ProcessInput(Confirmation context)
   {
        if (context.Confirmed)
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            await Task.Run(()=>DoSomethingService.DoSomething());

            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

Essentially, the pattern describes a dialog oriented workflow that allows the user to initiate (and provide input to) a long running operation without locking the UI. A concrete example of this pattern might be a "Save As..." operation where the user clicks a "Save As..." button, then keys in a text value for filename in a popup dialog, then clicks the dialog OK button, then watches a spin animation while their data is saved under the specified filename.

In the provided code example, initiating this workflow will perform the following operations.

1.Raise the `Input_InteractionRequest` Raised event to display a dialog in the UI for the purpose of collecting user input.

2.Invoke the `ProcessInput` callback (triggered when the user completes the dialog).

3.Check the Confirmed property of the InteractionRequest context to determine if the dialog was confirmed or canceled.

4.If confirmed...

1.Set the `IsBusy` flag.
2. Make a service call to do something using async pattern without locking the UI.
3. Once the service is completed set the `IsBusy` flag to false

I use Nunit for unit testing and fake it easy for mocking. A sample test fixture would be like this

```
    [Test]

    public async void SampleTestFixture()
    {
         //Arrange
         var viewModel = A.Fake<MyViewModel>();
       ViewModel.ConfirmationRequest = A.Fake<InteractionRequest<IConfirmWithClose>>();



                ViewModel.ConfirmationRequest.Raised += (s, e) =>
                {
                    var context = e.Context as ConfirmationWithClose;
                    if (context != null) context.ConfirmedWithClose = false;
                    e.Callback();
                };

    // Act
     var command = (AsyncRelayCommand)ViewModel.DisplayInputDialogCommand ;
                await command.ExecuteAsync(null);

   // Assert
   // This assert fails because although we are awaiting on the command the command completes before the callback function executes the asynchronous service to do something.
// Need a way to make this assert pass because in the real world the service gets invoked and everything works as ex
        A.CallTo(() => ViewModel.DoSomethingService.DoSomething().MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);


    }
```

The `AsyncRelayCommand` is an implementation of the `ICommand` to allow the unit tests to wait till the asynchronous command to be completed.

```
public class AsyncRelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly RelayCommand _internalCommand;

    private readonly Func<Task> _executeMethod;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { _internalCommand.CanExecuteChanged += value; }
        remove { _internalCommand.CanExecuteChanged -= value; }
    }

    public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<Task> executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {
        if (executeMethod == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("executeMethod");
        }

        _executeMethod = executeMethod;
        _internalCommand = new RelayCommand(() => { }, canExecuteMethod);
    }

    public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<Task> executeMethod) : this(executeMethod, () => true) { }

    public Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter)
    {
        return _executeMethod();
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ExecuteAsync(parameter);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _internalCommand.CanExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        _internalCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}

public class AsyncRelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private readonly RelayCommand<T> _internalCommand;
    private readonly Func<T, Task> _executeMethod;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { _internalCommand.CanExecuteChanged += value; }
        remove { _internalCommand.CanExecuteChanged -= value; }
    }

    public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<T, Task> executeMethod, Func<T, bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {
        if (executeMethod == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("executeMethod");
        }

        _executeMethod = executeMethod;
        _internalCommand = new RelayCommand<T>(_ => { }, canExecuteMethod);
    }

    public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<T, Task> executeMethod) : this(executeMethod, _ => true) { }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter is T)
        {
            ExecuteAsync((T)parameter);
        }

        else throw new ArgumentException("Parameter should be of type " + typeof(T));
    }

    public Task ExecuteAsync(T parameter)
    {
        return _executeMethod(parameter);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _internalCommand.CanExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        _internalCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

The assertion in my test fails because the call back function executes asynchronously and the assert happens before the callback function invokes the service and the service is completed .If any one can suggest a good solution to unit test the code in the asynchronous function and make the assert pass, it would be a really helpful.

Comment: Are you sure your "SaveFlowcommand" ever runs ? Your ViewModel is a mock. The ViewModel.SaveFlowCommand won't do anything at all

Comment: Your unit test method doesn't have an async signature, so how are you able to use an await in it?

Comment: @cscmh99,@O.O thanks for pointing out the errors ,I have edited the question to add async keyword to the test fixture and changed the SaveFlowCommand in the test fixture to DisplayInputDialogCommand .The code provided above is just a sample code to illustrate the problem that it is not possible for the unit test to wait and assert till the call back function gets completed

Comment: @VasudevanKannan You didn't get my point or what I saw is wrong at your unit test. It is completely possible for the test to wait for an async task to complete. The problem is that your viewmodel instance in the test is FAKE. There's nothing to execute and that's why the task completed instantly with NOTHING executed. It has to be a real instance when you try to test assert any target. You cannot test against mock object.

Comment: @cscmh99 You can check out in debugger that once you create a fake object and call a method on it the actual method on the object will get called and the code in the method body will get executed ,please check out the new comments I have added. Please note that I understand that the unit test will wait till the AsyncRelayCommand get completed , but the problem in this case is that the AsyncRelayCommand cannot return the task for the unit test to wait on because the actual task is returned by the call back function and not by the raise method.

Comment: @cscmh99  // Act
     var command = (AsyncRelayCommand)ViewModel.DisplayInputDialogCommand ;
                await command.ExecuteAsync(null);
Eventhough the viewmodel is mock the DisplayInputDialog method will get called and the then InteractionRequest.Raise method will get called which will in turn call the call back function which will invoke the service call

Comment: @cscmh99 https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/wiki/Default-fake-behavior Please check out this link, 
Non-overideable members cannot be faked
Methods and properties can only be faked if they are declared on a faked interface, or are declared abstract or virtual on a faked class. If none of these conditions hold, then a member cannot be faked, just as it could not be overridden in a derived class.

When such a member is invoked on the fake, the original behavior will be invoked. Since the above conditions hold good for the DisplayInputDialog  method for sure it will get invoked